Android BLE read data from different devices simultaneously
I have to start the developing about a new Android application. This application should to connect of 3 different device simultaneously in BLE.
My question is: The Gatt server can allow me to connect on 3 device simultaneously and get data from this 3 device simultaneously ?

You can connect to 3 devices and request data from one device after another

Ok so if I understand correctly, I cannot get data from these three devices in the same time but I can connect to 3 devices and read data from one device for time. Right?

Since there is only one Bluetooth antenna in your Android device you can only request data one after another. But that can be very quick. I just wanted to mention that there is no such thing as simultameously reading multiple devices

From the API point of view, you can interact with multiple devices simultaneously. Just as you can have multiple http requests running at the same time. Don't think too much about the scheduling in the Bluetooth chip or network card.
